# What is the maximum capacity of Azure Blob Storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

If I am creating an Azure Storage Account v2 then what is the maximum capacity of (or maximum size) of files we can store in the blob storage? I see some docs talking about 500 TB as the limit. Does that mean once the storage account reaches that 500 TB limit then it will stop accepting the uploads? Or is there a way to store more files by paying more?

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the region. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits US and Europe can have up to 2PB Storage accounts. All other regions are 500TB. As mentioned by Alfred below, you can request an increase if you need to (see new max sizes here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-larger-higher-scale-storage-accounts/)

I have yet to see a storage account hit the limit, but I would anticipate you would hit an error trying to upload a file at max capacity. I would advise designing your application to make use of multiple storage accounts to avoid hitting this limit (if you are expecting to exceed 500TB).

Answer (score 0):

you can ask support to increase

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-larger-higher-scale-storage-accounts/